# Як грамотно сказати "светлО"?

Tags: переклад

Стикнулася з перепоною під час перекладу "на улице пока еще светло". Пошуки в словниках результатів не дали. Що порадите?

Comment: 1. Недостатньо просто навести слово іншою мовою, Ви маєте пояснити його значення українською. Навіть якщо Вам воно здається очевидним — однаково пояснити треба.  
2. Недостатньо просто сформулювати питання, треба показати самостійні спроби його вирішення. От Ви кажете: «Пошуки в словниках результатів не дали» — а в яких саме словниках Ви шукали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вас, мабуть, збило з пантелику існування іменника *сві́тло*. Іменник — це те, що відповідає на питання «хто?», «що?», «кого?», «чого?» тощо. Наприклад:

> У мене давно була звичка ховатись по всяких темних закутках та печерах, коли **світло** намучить мені очі, і я сидів там одиноко і ждав, поки перестануть іти сльози з очей, потім я знов ішов шукати **світла** (Леся Українка, «Сліпець», 1902).

Але є також прислівник *сві́тло* (пишеться так само, читається так само, навіть має той самий наголос). Прислівник — це те, що відповідає на питання «як?». Наприклад:

> Було досить **світло**, і тут о. Аркадій побачив, яким він вийшов зі своєї незвичайної подорожі (Микола Чернявський, «Vae victis!», 1904).
>
> Було ще досить **світло**, але він спустив завіску й засвітив коло столу електрику (Валер'ян Підмогильний, «Повість без назви», 1934).

Вас, можливо, турбує, що якщо Ви напишете прислівник *світло* (як? дуже світло), то його можуть помилково сприйняти як іменник *світло* (що? яскраве світло)? Але хіба це проблема? От, наприклад, Франко пише:

> В однім його вікні було ще **світло**, очевидно, що Іцик мусив ще не спати, бо вікно було іменно з його кабінету (Іван Франко, «Борислав сміється», 1881).

Тут можна сприйняти і як «у вікні було ще доволі світло», і як «у вікні було ще якесь світло» — але хіба це сильно змінює сенс? У крайньому разі, якщо Вам вкрай важливо, щоб сприйняли саме як прислівник (чи навпаки, як іменник), Ви можете підкреслити це додатковими словами чи конструкцією речення (он як я зробим із «доволі світло» і «якесь світло»).

Також можна використати синонімічні слова чи словосполучення, зокрема:

- *видно*:

  > Робив лад у хаті, але то було вліті надвечором, і було ще **видно**, сонце ще лиш зайшло (Ольга Кобилянська, «Земля», 1901).
- *видко* (хоч у словниках це слово й [позначене як розмовне](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=8634&page=310), але його вживають й у літературі):

  > В кухні вже не було жовтого світла сонця, але ще було досить **видко**… (Володимир Винниченко, «Голота», 1905).
- *не темно*:

  > Було **не темно**, але і не так яскраво, як у центрі (Улас Самчук, «Віднайдений рай», 1936).

<sub>На майбутнє (це має бути написано не тут, а в коментарях до запитання, але про всяк випадок продублюю тут, щоб було помітніше):

1. Недостатньо просто навести слово іншою мовою, Ви маєте пояснити його значення українською. Навіть якщо Вам воно здається очевидним — однаково пояснити треба.

2. Недостатньо просто сформулювати питання, треба показати самостійні спроби його вирішення. От Ви кажете: «Пошуки в словниках результатів не дали» — а в яких саме словниках Ви шукали?</sub>